Showing $\inf _{a \neq 0} \frac{\left\|a^2\right\|}{\|a\|^2}\leq \inf _{a \neq 0} \frac{\|\hat{a}\|_{\infty}}{\|a\|}$ in a commutative banach algebra
Suppose $A$ is a commutative Banach algebra, and let $u=\inf _{a \neq 0} \frac{\left\|a^2\right\|}{\|a\|^2}$, $v=\inf _{a \neq 0} \frac{r(a)}{\|a\|}$ ($r(a)$ is the spectral radius of $a$). I need to show $ u \leq v$.
I want to prove that for any nonzero $a\in A$, $\frac{\left\|a^2\right\|}{\|a\|^2}\leq \frac{r(a)}{\|a\|}$ but I don't know how.

Are you sure you wrote the correct inequality? At least for your stronger inequality if we consider $A\subset M_3(\mathbb{C})$ being an algebra, generated by the nilpotent matrix $a$ (the Jordan block), then the left-hand side is positive while the right-hand side is zero...

@AlekseiKulikov I don’t think that works. If your $A$ contains a nilpotent, then it contains some nonzero $a$ whose square is $0$ (just raise your nilpotent element to appropriate power). So both sides would be $0$.

@DavidGao yes, that's why I specifically was talking only about a stronger second inequality.

@AlekseiKulikov Ah, you’re absolutely right. Sorry, I didn’t notice the second stronger inequality the OP mentioned at all.

If $u=0$, there is nothing to prove, so let further $u>0$. For every $b\ne 0$ in your algebra we have $$\frac{\|b^8\|}{\|b\|^8}=\frac{\|b^8\|}{\|b^4\|^2}\cdot \frac{\|b^4\|^2}{\|b^2\|^4}\cdot \frac{\|b^2\|^4}{\|b\|^8}\geqslant u^7.$$
Do the same for the exponent $2^k$ instead 8, take the root of degree $2^k$, and let $k$ tend to infinity. You get in the limit $$\frac{r(b)}{\|b\|}\geqslant u.$$
Now take the infimum over $b$.

You might want to address the case where $A$ contains nilpotent elements separately. Otherwise this proof works perfectly. +1

@DavidGao ok, I specified that $u=0$ is a trivial case

Thanks, that's amazing..

We have that $\frac{|b^2|^4}{|b|^8}\ge u^4$ by definition and from the inequality I'm guessing that we have $\frac{|b^4|^2}{|b^2|^4}\ge u^2$ and $\frac{|b^8|}{|b^4|^2}\ge u$ too but if correct how are these two proved? Thanks

@Dabed infimum of $F(a)=|a^2|/|a|^2$ does not exceed any specific value of $F$, like $F(b^4)$
